# Is appropriating an already built structure a valid strategy?

Tags: unturned

Let's say I'm looking to get myself a nice looking base, where only I can get in. Would building an metal door/frame and placing it on a vanilla structure be a valid strategy?

In other words, what are the differences between placing an iron door on a default building, rather than one built by players, on a multiplayer (vanilla) server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few variables, pros and cons for both.  Here's a short breakdown for pros and cons on "where to place your metal Door" [essentially]:

***Default Structure:***

**PROS:**

-Naturally Spawns some Items.

-Solid structure that cannot be destroyed [besides your door].

-Easier to fortify [windows, barbed wire, sand bags ect...].

**CONS:**

-People will be coming around your "fort" a lot, risking your door being blown down.

-Trapped inside [in most cases] during siege.

***Created Structure:***

**PROS:**

-Multiple Entrances/Exits/Window Escapes

-Built to your own Specs/Location

-Built with what you want [granted there will be a lot of gathering]

**CONS:**

-A LOT of gathering

-Your Structure can be completely destroyed

-No Naturally spawning items

This is really just a couple of the pros/cons of these potential options.  I personally would recommend fortifying a default structure while you gather materials for a strong fort somewhere out in the woods.  I hope this helps out!  Good luck out there!

Comment: Why did you not consider Zombies spawning inside the vanilla structure?